# Color differences / compression artefact using Sharp / NPM / Nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, image-processing, sharp

I've been working on a bigger app that pack 3D models together in nodeJS, and notice something I bumped into something I cannot resolve after hours of researches.

I did manage to get my basic problem into a few line of code.

```
import Sharp from 'sharp'


async function process(){

var sharpOriginal = Sharp('./samples/checker.jpg')

const sharpNew      = Sharp({
    create: {
        
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        channels: 3,
        background: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 }
    }
}) 

var  op = {
    input: await sharpOriginal.toBuffer(),
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 100
}

var extractedImage = sharpOriginal.extract( op )

extractedImage.jpeg({quality:100})

var composite = [
    
        {
            input: await extractedImage.toBuffer(),
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        }
    ]
    sharpNew.composite(composite).jpeg({quality:100}).toFile('./samples/extract.jpg')
}

process()
```

Basically, using sharp, https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp, v0.33.2

1 ) **Importing an image**

2 ) **extracting a portion into another one**

3 ) **Compositing it into a new one, and save it, leads to color changes. I'm using a basic UV-checker jpg :**

[image]

There is the result :

[image]

Using gimp to compare colors :

[image]

Original color : bcd300

[image]

Extracted color : c6c724

[image]

We can also notice a neat color difference between left : extracted / right : original

[image]

Is there a way to get all those operation without altering any of the color informations ?

Comment: if you wanted to debug this, you should first question the wisdom of saving as jpeg. next you should want to investigate the exact color spaces that are involved here, i.e. what the file metadata says and what the libraries say, if they even know.